# IP Address and Domain Name Restrictions in IIS 8.5

Tags: security, iis

I must me misunderstanding something simple here, and hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

I'm trying to restrict access to a folder in IIS. I have set it up to **DENY ALL**.
Now I want to add an **ALLOW** for a domain name rather than an IP address, using IP Address and Domain Name Restrictions

However, the dialog to add an allow is quite confusing. It makes me believe that I can enter a domain name, but the field is labelled IP Address, and the error indicates IP address only allowed here.

Does anyone know if using a domain name is permitted?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, you have to enable domain name restrictions first :)

Click "Edit Feature Settings" on the far right panel of IP Address and Domain Name Restrictions feature. Then you will see this:

[image]

Tick ENABLE DOMAIN NAME RESTRICTIONS
Then when you go to add and allow/deny entry, you will see a new field at the bottom which will accept a domain name as per below.

[image]